# Deploying Django Project with Supervisor and Gunicorn getting FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details) error

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

Im trying to launch my django project using [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/16/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-7.html) tutorial. I am currently setting up gunicorn and supervisor. These are the configs...

Here is my Gunicorn config:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="smart_suvey"
DIR=/home/smartsurvey/mysite2
USER=smartsurvey
GROUP=smartsurvey
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/smartsurvey/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myproject.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../venv/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

This is my supervisor config:
[program:smartsurvey]

```
command=/home/smartsurvey/gunicorn_start
user=smartsurvey
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/smartsurvey/logs/gunicorn.log
```

When Ive saved my supervisor, i run `sudo supervisorctl reread` followed by `sudo supervisorctl update`. These throw no errors.

I then run `sudo supervisorctl status smartsurvey`, which gives the error `smartsurvey  FATAL   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`

This is my first time putting my project on the internet so help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: what's in `/home/smartsurvey/logs/gunicorn.log`? my guess is your project is not called myproject but smartsurvey and you didn't update the run file. but the log file should tell you more..

Comment: Did you see : "Exited too quickly (process log may have details)" ?